# PHP site works fine in XAMPP, but redirects too many times on linux

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, apache2

So on XAMPP on windows I have my site up and running. But when copying the exact same files to a linux host running apache2, I get:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
>
> This page isn’t working
>
> 172.168.1.3 redirected you too many times.
>
> Try clearing your cookies.

The code is:

```
<?php
require_once('model/user.php');
session_start();
$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'Login';
$user = new User();
$user->checkCookie();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!isset($_POST['username'])) {
        // no username error
    } else if(!isset($_POST['password'])) {
        // no password error
    } else {
        $user = new User();
        if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {
           if($user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['remember']) == TRUE) {
                header('Location: /cliserv/search.php');
            }
        } else {
            if($user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], FALSE) == TRUE) {
                header('Location: /cliserv/search.php');
            }
        }
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    header('Location: /cliserv/search.php');
} else {
    require_once('view/login.php');
}
```

I've found that the issue is in the "model/user.php" file. If I comment out the 'require_once()' statements at the top of that file:

```
if (!class_exists('Campsite')) {
    require_once('campsite.php');
}
if (!class_exists('DB')) {
    require_once('database.php');
}
if (!class_exists('SearchData')) {
    require_once('searchData.php');
}
```

the site doesn't have the redirect error - but obviously the site then doesn't function, as the classes haven't been loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: so the issue is in one of the files, that you haven't included in the question?

Comment: I don't think it is an issue within the files. I have moved all the require_once() statements into the file the browser visits and it now works perfectly. Maybe it's to do with the initial file requesting a file that then requests another etc. but not sure why that wouldn't error out in XAMPP.

Comment: @henry it's about file encode type. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, It's about your session_start & working with sessions.

You must change file type to `UTF-8 without BOM`. That should be work.

You can enable display errors & then replace your `header('Location: ');` to `exit();`

to see have any error or not !

If have any error about unable to start_session(); just need to change file type to `UTF-8 without BOM`.

You must do it for all included files.